# Java, programming a Currency Calculator, stops at first JOptionPane and keeps running

Tags: java, joptionpane

Im a fresh student trying to learn Java programming. This week we have an assignment to program a currency calculator  using two classes. Im having some issues while running the program, namely keeping it going. We have to use JOptionPane to ask for input and show output, and Im not entirely sure how Im supposed to keep them "popping up". Im hoping that I could get some pointers in how Im supposed to keep the program running.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class runner {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do
            {
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type in the number of kroner you want to check: ");
                double kroner = input.nextInt();
                Object[] options = {"Euro", "Yen"};
                int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "you wrote: " + kroner + "do you want to convert this to euro or yen?", "Choose an alternative", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);

            Functions operationObject = new Functions();

            if (choice == 0)
            {
                operationObject.kronerTilEuro(kroner);
            }
            else if (choice == 1)
            {
                operationObject.kronerTilYen(kroner);
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You need to pick one of the alternatives!");
            }
        }
        while (!input.hasNextInt());
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I am not happy");
            input.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Ive to tried to create a loop so that the first panel will show up again if the user gives input that is not an integer, but without any luck. Please let me know if there is something that Ive missed.

Comment: i didn't realize your main question , did you mean your program Stuck in your `do-while`?

Comment: When I run the program, it will only show the first JOptionPane window. After Ive given my input, the window closes and the program keeps  running. Nothing happens

Comment: if you find my answer useful , check it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is here , you are using a `showInputDialog` reading sth from user , after that you have a `input.nextInt()` without any warn in your program , it waits for you until you enter a number :

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type in the number of kroner you want to check: ");
double kroner = input.nextInt();
```

first replace `input.nextInt()` with `input.nextDouble()`, you are reading a `double` not a `int`

i'll tell you two ways :

1 - replace the `showInputDialog` with `showMessageDialog` :

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Type in the number of kroner you want to check: ");
double kroner = in.nextDouble();
```

2 - try to read with `showInputDialog` and parse it's `String` to `Double`

```
double kroner = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type in the number of kroner you want to check: "));
```

Comment: Your second point worked! The program is a success! Thank you :)

Comment: @mortex both of them work , in the first method you must enter `input` in the `console` , in the second one you must enter it in `InputDialog`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // amount
        Double amount = null;
        while (amount == null) {
            String amountStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type in the numeric amount kroner oyu want to check");
            if(amountStr==null)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pleae enter a numeric amount", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            else
                try {
                    amount = Double.valueOf(amountStr);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "only 0-9 and . are allowed", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
        }
        // option
        String[] options = new String[] { "-> EUR", "-> YEN" };
        int selection = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Please select the target currency", "Title",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, null);
        String option = options[selection];
        // result
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, doSomethingFancy(amount, option), "Result",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }

    private static String doSomethingFancy(Double amount, String option) {
        // here you want to do the calculations
        return amount + " kroener " + option;
    }

}
```